# Create an object inside foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a requirement to create an object in following format inside foreach loop

```
var array = ['sent', 'flag']
```

need an output object like the following format

```
obj = {
sent: true,
flag: true
}
```

Tried

```
array.forEach(function(data){
    console.log('data', data);
    var obj = {}
    obj.data = true;
})
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create the object outside of the loop and then use bracket notation to assign the property.

In your code in each iteration of the array, you are creating a local object and is setting a property called `data` in it.

```js
var array = ['sent', 'flag'];

var obj = {}
array.forEach(function(data) {
  obj[data] = true;
})

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var array = ['sent', 'flag']
var obj = {};

array.forEach(function(el) {
  if (!obj[el]) {
    obj[el] = true;
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

use reduce and a re-usable function instead of forEach:

```
function setTrue(a,b){ a[b]=true; return a; }
var obj1 = ['sent', 'flag'].reduce(setTrue, {});
var obj2 = ['sent2', 'flag2'].reduce(setTrue, {});
```

the advantage to reduce() is not having to code custom object variable name-using anon functions for each array harvest.